# Having problems generating a star pattern in python suggested from a book but getting different results

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new on Python and I am following a book that purposes the following excercise:

Write a program to generate the following pattern in Python:

```
*
**
***
****
```

The suggested code is:

```
n = input('Enter the number of rows: ')
m = int(n)
*k = 1
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(i, i + 2):
        print('*', end = " ")
    print()
```

and enter `n=5`.This lead me to ask to questions. The first one is the `*k=1`, I am asumming the '*' is a typo on the book since my program does not run with it. However i am not seeing that `k` is being used within the loop. My second question is that I do not understand why my outcome is different than the one I get (once removed the '*'). This is what I get when `n=5`:

```
**
**
**
**
**
```

Comment: What book exactly are you following? Could we see it online?

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `for j in range(i, i + 2)` means?

Answer (score 1):

This works for your problem. In python, you can multiply strings. It will be useful for the problem. *k is a typo.

```
n = input(' num rows: ')
n = int(n)
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print ('*' * i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. I am pretty sure the `*k = 1` is a typo.

```
n = int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))
k = 1
for i in range(n):
    print(k * '* ', end = "\n")
    k += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you don't want to use multiplication approach:

```
n = input('Enter the number of rows: ')
m = int(n)

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(1, i + 2):
        print('*', end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: This was really useful, thank you very much. Would you help me to understand what the ```end``` argument does in the ```print()``` function?

Comment: the ```end``` argument is an optional argument to the print function that was introduced in Python 3.x. The default behavior of ```print``` function is to print a newline (\n) after all the arguments are printed. Here, we specified a blank space " " as the character to be printed instead of the newline (thus keeping all the "\*" s in the same line)

The second ```print()``` at the end of the for loop is to print the newline after each line of "\*" s

Answer (score 0):

```
def printStarsInTriangeForm(count):
    for i in (range(1, count + 1)):
        print("*" * i)
```

This is one way. :)

Answer (score 0):

yea `*k = 1` cant be right, you can delete it.
Your mistake or the mistake in the book is the line:

```
for j in range(i, i + 2):
```

if you type i * 2 it works:

```
for j in range(i, i * 2):
```

and if you want no spaces between the starts you need to change the print in the loop to:

```
print("*",end="")
```

i just removed the space in the "end".

and a better way you can do this is

```
m = int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))
for i in range(m + 1):
    print(i * "*")
```